# Determine range for one value in a column, use to run function over same range in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

### Summary

I want to have a column in my spreadsheet that does 2 things.

1) In an ordered column, it will return the range where the column contains a specified value.

2) It will run a function (i.e., =SUM(), =AVERAGE(), etc.) over that same range in a different column.

### Examples

#### Original

```
| NAME  | VAL | FOO |
|-------|-----|-----|  
|   A   |  3  |     |  
|   A   |  2  |     |  
|   A   |  4  |     |  
|   A   |  3  |     |  
|   B   |  2  |     |  
|   B   |  2  |     |  
|   B   |  1  |     |  
|   C   |  6  |     |  
|   C   |  5  |     |
```

#### Average

I would want to get the average of VAL for each NAME. I would want the result to be:

```
| NAME  | VAL | FOO |
|-------|-----|-----|  
|   A   |  3  |  3  |  
|   A   |  2  |  3  |  
|   A   |  4  |  3  |  
|   A   |  3  |  3  |  
|   B   |  2  | 1.7 |  
|   B   |  2  | 1.7 |  
|   B   |  1  | 1.7 |  
|   C   |  6  | 5.5 |  
|   C   |  5  | 5.5 |
```

#### Sum

Another example would be to get the sum of VAL for each NAME.

```
| NAME  | VAL | FOO |
|-------|-----|-----|  
|   A   |  3  |  12 |  
|   A   |  2  |  12 |  
|   A   |  4  |  12 |  
|   A   |  3  |  12 |  
|   B   |  2  |  5  |  
|   B   |  2  |  5  |  
|   B   |  1  |  5  |  
|   C   |  6  |  11 |  
|   C   |  5  |  11 |
```

Comment: What have you tried? `SUMIFS()` or `AVERAGEIFS()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having "NAME" ordered makes it easy. If "NAME" is in `A1`. Enter this into `C2` for the sum, then fill down:

```
=IF(A2=A3,C3,SUMIF($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2))
```

Enter this into `C2` for the average, then fill down:

```
=IF(A2=A3,C3,AVERAGEIF($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2))
```

Note that the result in `C2` won't be what you want until you fill down.

**Update for MAXIF**

If you don't have Excel 2016, you'll have to use an array formula (commit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
=IF(A2=A3,C3,MAX(IF($A$2:A2=A2,$B$2:B2)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a beginner and spending time with your logic made this click for me how to get the ranges of two columns to interact in a coherent way.